# For a set of points P, connected by weighted edges (distances) I need a path through all points while minimizing the travel on any edge longer than X

Tags: graph-traversal, traveling-salesman, genetic-algorithms

For a given set of coordinates (lat/lng) I need a path which will visit each coordinate only once. The path needs to be selected to minimize the number of times the haversine distance between two subsequent points along the path is greater than X (ex: 200 miles).

The practical application:

I have airports on a map. I have a string of LED lights which are connected by a fixed distance of wire between them. I want the optimal path between all the airports where I minimize the number of times I need to splice additional wire into the string.

Suggestions on the approach? Maybe some type of genetic algorithm implementation?

Comment: @D.W. But, it's so clear in my head.. :-)  I've tried to clarify it again and give some insight into my actual application.

Comment: That helped, thank you!  Since this is a practical problem, about how many points do you expect to have?

Comment: Typically under 100 points. On occasion up to 800 points.

Comment: I think it won't be too important, but you may want to clarify what you mean by "distance": is it a Euclidean distance, or is it a distance on the sphere (since you are using lat/lng).

Comment: I've clarified it to be haversine distance. However, as you mention, the problem doesn't really change.

Comment: Do you need a path or simply have all nodes be connected with the least amount of string? A minimal spanning tree is easy to find and will do that. I ask because of your target usecase.

Comment: @orlp I need all nodes connected not with the least amount of string, but rather all nodes connected minimizing the number of times an edge is greater than X. An edge being greater than X is a very expensive operation for me. In my practical application it requires cutting and soldering wire, so I want a path through all the vertices which minimizes the number of times that happens.

Comment: @jr. Yes, but do you insist a *path* (one long line), or is a *tree* connecting all nodes  also okay?

Comment: @orlp Good point. Each node has a single input and a single output. So, I guess a single path.

Answer (score 2):

Create a graph from the airport coordinates where edges have the haversine distance as weights.  Since the graph is a *metric graph*, you can apply [Christofides algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm).  This algorithm is a $\frac 3 2$-appoximation, which means that it gives a solution which is not worse than 50% longer than the optimal.

However, since you want to also minimize the number of long edges, you can remove all edges that are longer than you would like, *but* you now have a non-metric graph (it does no longer satisfy the triangle inequality).

One related problem is the [Bottleneck traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck_traveling_salesman_problem), in which you want to find a Hamiltonian path that minimizes the longest edge.  Since your original graph is a metric graph, you can apply the 2-approximation to get an algorithm in which the longest edge is not more than twice possible.

---

Since you seem to be set on using genetic algorithm, you can consider using both of these algorithms for seeding the initial pool for the GA.  Run both algorithms many times to get many different solutions (introduce some randomness), and you might have a very good starting pool.

Answer (score 0):

Build a graph with one vertex per point.  Add an edge of length 0 between a pair of vertices $v,w$ if they are at most $X$ distance apart; otherwise add an edge of length 1.  Then, use any existing algorithm for the travelling salesman problem in this graph.  Solving the TSP in this graph will solve your problem.  There are many algorithms, heuristics, etc., including many software packages you can download that implement them for you.  (Note that this TSP instance will be an instance of metric TSP, which may enable some algorithms that take into account that additional structure.)

This could reasonably be called an instance of (0,1)-TSP. I have not been able to find any papers in the literature on (0,1)-TSP, though I have found several on approximation algorithms for (1,2)-TSP.

Comment: So, you are saying don't have the edge be the actual distance, but have it be the output of the function f(v,w) = if (dist(v,w) > X) 1 else 0;

Comment: @jr., yes, that's right.

Comment: Would another reasonable solution be a genetic TSP algorithm where a penalty is added to the cost when then the distance is > X? This is the solution I was starting with for the TSP and seeing if I could adapt it compared to having to implement another TSP variant in python.

Comment: I'm experimenting with using a genetic algorithm and making any distance > X be squared. I am also stoping when I have the number of edges which exceed X be zero, since this is my optimal solution. I need to read more about local minima, because I seem to get better results just running the GA multiple times, compared to letting it run longer.

Comment: @jr., no, none of those are reasonable, they solve a different problem.  If you want to solve the problem that you specified in your question, then you should replace all edge costs with either 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks, I will test more. I appreciate the dialog here.

Comment: In my testing with this GA code I am using (https://github.com/lccasagrande/TSP-GA), I am getting far better solutions using dist^2 compared to just using 1/0. I suspect it has to do with the way the GA is selecting the best candidates from the population. When the distance is either one or zero, the population is split into two sets 1 or zero. When you penalize the distances over my X threshold by making them arbitrarily large it arrives at an optimal solution faster. I am going to search and/or implement another non-GA TSP algorithm I can use in Python so I can further test.

Comment: @jr., ok, I guess I didn't take into account the challenges with GA.  Glad that it helped!  Sorry for leading you astray with an unhelpful comment.